# Spark on Yarn remote debugging in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, remote-debugging

I need to debug my scala/spark application running using yarn client mode.

I am not sure how to do this in intellig idea..follwing this https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/15030/spark-remote-debugging.html

it is however work for eclispe.

I first try to run

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5002
```

Then when I go to remote debugging in the IDE

[image]
However, the idea gives me a connection refused error..

Comment: Do you have the same port number in IntelliJ run configuration and SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS?

Comment: Ok just change the "host" from localhost to the IP of my cluster running yarn..however, I am not sure how to put line breakpoints..I see remote files in the cluster using the remote host file viewer plugin in intellig idea...

Comment: You need to have same files in your IntelliJ IDEA project in order to debug them.